# Layout Help, Disappearing LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, interface, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to design a simple layout with 2 buttons in a horizontal linear layout centered at the bottom of the page (so layout_gravity="bottom").  And I also need a vertical linear layout that's centered in the screen that can hold 3 TextViews (that are implemented later in the program, so just need a LinearLayout to be ABLE to hold 3 TextViews).

I can get the buttons to their right spots (even though I would like them more seperated), but every time I try to make the TextViews LinearLayout it either doesn't appear or makes the other one disappear.  I've been trying to get this down for awhile...can anybody help?  Thanks

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/background">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="100dip">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_label"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/repeat_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/repeat_label"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>   
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: None of the answers are really working for me...still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`linearlayout2` is vertical layout with children positioned in the center

Is that what you need?

[image]

`EditText` with "Some text" value is added through java with both `LayoutParams` set to `WRAP_CONTENT`

Answer (score 0):

Quick idea:

Set the vertical `LinearLayout`'s height to 0dp, and use `weight` to give it the rest of all the remaining space after your other view is laid out, e.g. give it `android:layout_weight="1"`

The tricky part is needing to set the height to 0 so it actually uses the `layout_weight`.

*Caveat: It's late and I've had a couple glasses of wine. :)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the horizontal `LinearLayout` of 2 `Button`s has its height set to `wrap_content`.
Also you can take a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)and keep two `LinearLayout` of vertical and horizontal orientation respectively.

This code shall suffice:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignparentbottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="100dip">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next_label"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/repeat_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/repeat_label"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>   
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerinparent="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Caveat: casing of properties could be different so correct them.

Comment: What do you mean relative layout?  I'm a little confused...my code just makes the textview layout a mess...

Comment: Like Linear Layout there is another layout named Relative Layout  which allows user to arrange the controls in it as per convenience .It gives properties like "layout_alignleftof" and many other .I have added a reference in my answer,you an go through it.

Comment: I'll see what I can do with that, thanks, it's a little confusing